# Having 2 auth clients results in 404 on calendar event creation

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm trying to create 2 calendar events across 2 calendars using the Google Node.js API client library in a single function. I'm using 2 separate auth objects that I'm retrieving like so:

```
var auth1 = await google.auth.getClient({ credentials: config.account1Creds, scopes: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events"] }); 
var auth2 = await google.auth.getClient({ credentials: config.account2Creds, scopes: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events"] });
```

I can create the event on the first calendar fine, but when I create the event on the 2nd calendar, I get a 404 Not Found back from the Google Calendar API server.

If I comment out the first `var auth1 = await google.auth...` line and only create the event on the 2nd calendar, everything is fine and the event is created successfully.

It kinda feels as if the first time `getClient` is called, it sets a global auth object that gets used for all remaining API requests and it can't be replaced, but thats just a hunch I have and I don't actually know.

Anybody have any ideas why this is happening?

**EDIT:**

```
GetGoogleCalendarService: async function(credentials)
{
    var auth = await google.auth.getClient({ credentials: credentials, scopes: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events"] });

    return google.calendar({ version: "v3", auth: auth });
},

InsertCalendarEvent: function(calendar, entry, callback)
{
    calendar.events.insert(entry, callback);
},

SendInvitesToEvent: async function (request, response)
{
    //build the calendar event
    var entry = {
        ...
    }

    //insert into operations calendar
    var opsCal = await Events.GetGoogleCalendarService(config.GetConfig().OpsCalendarCredentials);
    Events.InsertCalendarEvent(mainCal, entry);

    //insert into public calendar
    var publicCal = await Events.GetGoogleCalendarService(config.GetConfig().PublicCalendarCredentials);

    Events.InsertCalendarEvent(publicCal, entry, async function(err, event) 
    {
        //err: 404 Not Found
        ...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

- You want to insert events to 2 calendars using 2 clients.

  - Client "A" inserts an event to Calendar "A".
  - Client "B" inserts an event to Calendar "B".
- You are using googleapis of Node.js.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? In this modification, I separated retrieving `auth` by each credential.

#### Modified script:

```
const { google } = require("googleapis");

function insertEvent(calendar, calendarId) {
    // insert event
}

async function getService(c) {
  var auth = await google.auth.getClient({
    credentials: c,
    scopes: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events"]
  });
  return google.calendar({ version: "v3", auth: auth });
}

function main() {
  getService(config.account1Creds).then(calendar => {
    insertEvent(calendar, "### calendarId ###");
  });
  getService(config.account2Creds).then(calendar => {
    insertEvent(calendar, "### calendarId ###");
  });
}

main();
```

#### Note:

- This is a sample script. So please modify this for your situation.

In my environment, I could confirm that this script works. But if this didn't work and this modification was not the result you want, I apologize.

### Edit:

From your current script, I modified as follows.

- Is `opsCal` `mainCal`? In my modification, `opsCal` is used as `mainCal`.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
//insert into operations calendar
var opsCal = await Events.GetGoogleCalendarService(config.GetConfig().OpsCalendarCredentials);
Events.InsertCalendarEvent(mainCal, entry);

//insert into public calendar
var publicCal = await Events.GetGoogleCalendarService(config.GetConfig().PublicCalendarCredentials);

Events.InsertCalendarEvent(publicCal, entry, async function(err, event) 
{
    //err: 404 Not Found
    ...
}
```

To:

```
Events.GetGoogleCalendarService(config.GetConfig().OpsCalendarCredentials).then(
  opsCal => {
    Events.InsertCalendarEvent(opsCal, entry);
  }
);
Events.GetGoogleCalendarService(config.GetConfig().PublicCalendarCredentials).then(
  publicCal => {
    Events.InsertCalendarEvent(publicCal, entry);
  }
);
```

Comment: Nope, I tried this, it doesn't work. Still getting a 404

Comment: @user1435899 Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Can you provide your whole script for replicating your issue? Of course, please remove your personal information. I would like to confirm it. If you can do, please add it to your question.

Comment: Cool, I've updated my question to include the code I'm now using.

Comment: @user1435899 Thank you for updating it. Although I'm not sure whether this is the result you want, I proposed a modification point at Edit section in my answer. Could you please confirm it? In my environment, I could confirm that this script works. But if this didn't work and this modification was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still getting the 404 :( Thanks for trying though, I appreciate it! I've decided to just add the second calendar as an attendee to the invite and then just add it to the one calendar, its not the approach we wanted, but it'll do for now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @user1435899 I apologize for the inconvenience. In my environment, I can confirm that the script that you provided works fine by modified as above. Because of this situation, I cannot find about your issue. So can you provide how to replicate your situation? Or, in order to find the issue, at first, can you test it using a simple script? My 1st script can be used for testing. By this, I would like to find your issue. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: @user1435899 I tested both scripts in my answer again. But I couldn't replicate your situation. Unfortunately, both scripts worked fine. I apologize for this situation. But I think that when this issue was resolved, we can obtain a big experience. So I would like to find the reason of your issue.